# How can we make two corrective shapekey driver values to work 50/50 percent each of them to avoid stacking when they move in the same direction?

Tags: rigging, drivers, shape-keys

As I show in my images, when my shapekey drivers both move in the same direction, their powers stacks to each other. I need them to not to stack.

Thanks in advance for replies.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe the simplest solution would by to either have one shapekey that does both legs at once, or deform that geometry with bones.

Comment: shouldn't this be pretty easy to do with changing the driver? can u pls show us your driver? or provide blend file?

Answer (score 3):

You need 3 shape keys: one for the left leg, one for the right leg and one for the armor part in the center. You create the shape key for the left leg going up and the other for the right leg going up. For the center part you create a shape key which you give the armor part's maximum movement.

Then you hover your mouse over let's say the left shape key's *Value* (not in the list of shape keys, below where you can enter the value), right-click and choose *Copy as New Driver*. Then switch to the center shape key and on the *Value* field right-click and choose *Paste Driver*.

Now, the center shape key would inherit whatever value you enter in the left shape key. But that's not what we want. Select the center shape key, right-click on the value and choose *Open Drivers Editor*.

The *Drivers Editor* shows the current way the driver works, the *Driven Property* > *Value* of the shape key "center". It is set to *Type* > *Averaged Value* and uses the specified data, the value from the shape key I have named "left".

[image: basic driver]

I'll switch the *Type* to *Scripted Expression*, there might be an ERROR message but that does not matter in this moment. I rename the variable below from "value" to "left" just for convenience. Afterwards I add another variable by pressing the *Add Input Variable* button.

[image: changing driver type]

On this new variable I first have to change the *Prop* to *Key* which you will find in the dropdown menu of the props.

[image: change prop type]

I click on the empty field behind the prop type, there should be only one item named "Key" which I choose. Then I copy the *Path* from the first variable and paste it in the *Path* of the new one. I change the name "left" to "right" (or whatever you named the second shape key for the other leg) and also rename the variable to "right", again just for convenience.

[image: editing the new variable]

The last thing to make it work is entering the mathematical expression to calculate the center driver's value: in the field below *Expression:* I enter: `max(left,right)` as formula. Important: left/right are the names of the variables, not how you named the shape keys if you used different names than me. You can press *Update Dependencies*, sometimes the drivers are not updated automatically. At least it does not hurt to update it.

[image: expression max value]

Now the center shape key always uses the maximum value of the left and right shape keys without adding them up. In the example below that's the value of the right leg (yes, my model looks terrible). By the way, I've seen in your screenshot that the shape keys for left and right leg already have drivers themselves - that is no problem, they can still be used as drivers for the armor.

[image: result]